# Is possible to create table by hibernate with specified qualifier

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, spring-boot

I try to create table by hibernate (ddl-auto=update). Results are tables only with default qualifier [dbo]. I wonder if there is an option how to change qualifier to something else (e.g. [db1]) ?

My application runs on Spring-Boot and hibernate.

I am looking for solution how can be qualifier defined.

This is how I create datasource :

```
DataSourceBuilder.create()
                        .url("jdbc:sqlserver://" + hostname + ":" + port + ";databaseName=" + schemaName + ";")
                        .driverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").username(username)
                        .type(com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.class).password(password).build();
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. What you call a "qualifier" is known as a schema in the sql server world. There are tons of examples of how to use them [here](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1&q=spring+boot+hibernate+custom+schema).

Comment: Hello @SeanLange. I don ´t really see what I am looking for. From my point of view the "schema" has two parts schemaName [dbName] and qualifier[dbo]. in result it looks like this [dbo].[dbName]. Is possible to defined a both of these parts ? thanks

Comment: Let me see if this helps. In the database world a schema is a collection of objects. So your example [dbo].[dbName]. Is [schema].[DatabaseName] And the google link I sent has tons of examples of how to use them.

Comment: The solution for me was. in database create new schema and assigned that schema as default schema into current user. then hibernate started to produce tables in desired (new default) schema. no changies in java needed.